# How can an oral antigen help meniere's syndrome?

Tags: immune-system, antigen, menieres-disease

Can giving a sublingual antigen to a virus (e.g. herpes) whilst concomitantly giving antiviral drugs help with meniere's syndrome? The aim being to encourage the Mucosal Associated Lymphoid Tissue (MALT) to have a different immune response to the virus and thus the meniere's symptoms are reduced.